# Firefox: Image transition, ease out to grayscale

Tags: css, firefox, css-transitions, css-filters

I have css that works in chrome, when I tested in Firefox, it will not work.
Here is code:

```
<div class="img">
<a href="/">
<img src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/8/80/Knut_IMG_8095.jpg" alt="Smiley face" height="400" width="600">
</a>
</div>



img {
      -webkit-transition: all 1s ease;
         -moz-transition: all 1s ease;
           -o-transition: all 1s ease;
          -ms-transition: all 1s ease;
              transition: all 1s ease;
    display: block;
    }

img:hover {
    -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%);
    display: block;
    }
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/X8LQk/2/

Comment: CSS filters are not implemented in FireFox.
You could fallback with a canvas image manipulation but this is just eye candy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are just using `-webkit-filter`, for Firefox you will need SVG filter

```
filter: url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns=\'http://www.w3.org/2000/svg\'><filter id=\'grayscale\'><feColorMatrix type=\'matrix\' values=\'0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0 0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0 0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0 0 0 0 1 0\'/></filter></svg>#grayscale");
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/mr_alien/X8LQk/5/)

---

The only issue with this is you won't be able to transit the grey effect except for Chrome as of now, you can check the compatibility at [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/filter) or at [Can I Use](http://caniuse.com/css-filters) for more details.

Comment: Image is gray, on hover goes to normal color, and no ease out/in.

Comment: This is an elegant solution and should be close enough to accept it.

Comment: Yes, it is, and I will accept it if no solution to go ease in/out. By the way you put filter in img instead in img:hover. http://jsfiddle.net/mr_alien/X8LQk/5/

Comment: @user3207567 this won't transit, as far as standard properties go, `filter` is not supported in firefox yet - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/filter as well as  http://caniuse.com/css-filters